# How to use the match Function with two criteria in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, range, match, worksheet

I am trying to use the „MATCH“ function  in order to get the Row (named RICRow) number of a name which is contained in the “RIC“ column (A). Because there are always two names in the RIC column (e.g.”Tom”) it is necessary to take the column(L) “RIC_FID” into consideration which contains a unique value corresponding to the names (e.g. 295). The VBA code below keeps yielding the error msg: type mismatch

```
RICRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(RIC & RIC_FID, protokoll.Range("A1:A500") & protokoll.Range("L1:L500"), 0)
```

Comment: you will either need to iterate the rows of the range and test or use Worksheet.Evaluate  `WorksheetFunction...` cannot be array type.

Comment: ^ Either that or apply an `AutoFilter` and get the range `SpecialCells(12).Row` property of the `Range` object.

Comment: can "Worksheet.Evaluate " be used in combination with "MATCH" such as Worksheet.Evaluate.Match(..?

Comment: [`.Evaluate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.evaluate) basically takes a formula how you would write it in a worksheet. Can I just note that a multi-criteria match is best found through boolean structures instead of concatenation which has a higher risk profile.

Comment: The Match would be a formula string like you would put on the sheet.  the `Worksheet` portion would be the actual worksheet: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.evaluate

Comment: Alright. That helps. I will try the "Evaluate" function. The boolean function returns a YES or NO there for i dont think it would help much as I am going to need the row number. Thank you all for the quick reply

Comment: I would help a lot =) > `=MATCH(1,(range1=criteria1)*(range2=criteria2),0)`. Just + the row where you start your ranges as `MATCH` returns the index number of the first `1` within the array.

Comment: my finished code would look like this: RICRow = protokoll.Evaluate(=match(1,(A1:A500)*(L1:L500),0))

Comment: You need to add the `""` around the formula.  Evaluate expects a text string that looks like a formula.

Comment: Thank you. This one seems to work. RICRow = protokoll.Evaluate("match(""" & RIC & "" & RIC_FID & """, A:A&L:L, 0)"). I just down know, why there are so many "" needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this one solved the issue:

```
RICRow = protokoll.Evaluate("match(""" & RIC & "" & RIC_FID & """, A:A&L:L, 0)")
```